# Restricting parts of boolean Google queries to one domain only

Tags: google-search

If I want to search this in Google Search,

> Keyword1 `OR` Keyword2 `OR` `(`Keyword3 `site:`SOMESITE.com`)`

In theory, this should find `Keyword1` or `Keyword2` on any webpage, and only `Keyword3` should be restricted to `SOMESITE.com`.

Instead, what happens is that all of the results are restricted to `SOMESITE.com`.

How do I phrase the query so that it finds `Keyword1` anywhere, `Keyword2` anywhere, and `Keyword3`, *but only* from `SOMESITE.com`?

Comment: Google takes those `()` as search queries, not operators. :)

Comment: So any idea what the proper operator would be in this case, if any?

Comment: None. Not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible.

If to take a look at [Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search), you'll see that the query is divided in two parts:

1. `Find pages with...`
2. `Then narrow your results by...`

Part `1.` allows combination of several strings using logical operators (`OR`, `AND`), but all options in part `2.` have a global scope, i. e., they effect the entire search.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think Google's Engine is that sophisticated. You are really doing 3 searches though Keyword3 site:SOMESITE.com, Keyword1, Keyword2.  
That's what tabs are for :)